# D3 Issues with time scale, calculating the position of items

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, graph-visualization

I am working on a bars chart that has uses a time scale on the x axis.

Each bar represents a month so all the dates are setted as YYYY-MM and when I load the data i parse it with:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse;
```

The issue is that how each month has a different amount of days, the some bars are closer that others instead of having all the same margin, as you can see on  this screenshot:

[image: barchart]

Here you can find the code, http://tributary.io/inlet/8700564

Thanks

Comment: What is the data on the y-axis? Depending on what it is we could normalized the width of each element. For example how many times X happened in some month.

Comment: its the amount of sales in this month. there will be only one bar per month.

Comment: Since it does not matter the amount of days in the month simple set the width of each bar to some static value. All of them could be 40 pixels for example. Change line 124: `var barWidth = 40;` And they are all the same width. http://tributary.io/inlet/8716416

Comment: but the issue is not the bar width. It is dinamic because it has 3 filters that shows 7 12 or 30 bars so I calculate the width based on the chart width / bars count. the issue is that there is different space width between them because of the difference in days between months. Also, in your code you can see that all the bars are very close to each other but there is a space on the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:  either use an ordinal (category) scale for the x-axis, which will give all the bars the same width, or set the width of each bar individually based on the length of the month.

To figure out the length of the month, you can use [d3 time intervals](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals) to do get the date of the start of the next month.  Then the width is just the difference between the two dates' positions on the xScale, possibly adjusted by padding to give some space between the bars.

```
rect.attr("x", function(d){return xScale(d.date) + padding;})
    .attr("width", function(d){
              return xScale( d3.time.month.offset(d.date, 1) )
                   - xScale(d.date)
                   - 2*padding;
        });
```

Comment: the issue is not the bar width, it is the space between bars. If you see between the second (february) and the third (march) there is no space (because february has 28 days) but between the others there is an space, but it different (some 1 px and some 2 px aprox) because some has 30 or 31 days.

Comment: The method I gave will give equal spacing, according to the "padding" you add in, by varying the bar width to fit the width of the month.  If you want equal spacing *and* equal bar width, use an ordinal scale, as in most bar chart examples, [like this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304).